# Loading a PE File and Launching it, how to capture the exit/return code

Tags: windows, winapi, portable-executable

I'm manually (in code that is) loading in a windows PE file and executing it succesfully with a call to its entry point as defined in the structure "IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32".  However as this value is a void returned function how do we 'read' the exit/return code that it provides?

i.e. when i call this (which is the PE file's entry point)

```
((void(*)(void))EntryAddr)();
```

Where does it place/put the exit code from its 'int main(...)' or 'int winmain(...)' call?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: For clarification (see comments below).  My Application loads an exe directly into memory using VirtualAllocEx and not any NtCreateProcess methods.

Comment: The C Runtime just calls [ExitProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) with the return value from `main`.

Comment: If the image uses the C runtime (very likely) and the current process is a managed app (i.e. `__scrt_is_managed_app` returns true), then `__scrt_common_main_seh` will just return instead of calling `ExitProcess`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, from what I can tell, Tim is loading the image in an existing process and calling the entry point -- for some unspecified reason. If the image uses the C runtime, then in most cases, as far as I know (I haven't actually tried this experiment), the common entry point `__scrt_common_main_seh` should call `ExitProcess`, making the question moot, unless it's loaded in a managed process, which is checked against the image of the current process (i.e. `GetModuleHandleW(NULL)`) by looking for a non-zero entry for the `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR` image data directory.

Comment: @eryk I was imagining this was the standard create process in memory. I'm doubtful that what you describe is feasible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I think that inference is a pretty big leap. Tim mentions nothing about creating a new process via `NtCreateProcess`, `NtAllocateVirtualMemory`, `NtCreateThread`,  etc, or by creating a suspended process and rewriting/replacing the memory of the image and the thread context. And if one can knowingly do all of that, I would hope one knows how to call `GetExitCodeProcess`.

Comment: Hi thanks for all your replies.  No i'm not calling NtCreateProcess i'm loading it directly into memory with VirtualAllocEx etc so don't technically have a process handle other than the one that is allocated with the exe i created (not the app i'm loading).  I'll investigate accessing the ExitProcess() function's results through the documentation and see where i end up.

Comment: Wow cool! You created your own loader, didn't you?  Though I don't have an answer, but I'd like you to share your code.  I'm very curious. How about hooking ExitPross by modifying the IAT?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share it, however this link should provide all the basic information you'd need to start (including a simplified example)... https://securityxploded.com/memory-execution-of-executable.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to "Eryk Sun" above, his solution was correct and this code does in fact work..

```
// call the entry point :: here we assume that everything is ok.
((void(*)(void))EntryAddr)();

DWORD exit;
GetExitCodeProcess(GetModuleHandle(NULL), &exit);
```